# Commerce discounts by day-of-week and by age

Tags: 7, commerce

I am creating a store where users can pay for attending events at a fixed rate of £7 for each event; that's the easy part.

The hard parts are as follows:

- Every Tuesday all events are half price (£3.50)
- Students are admitted any day of the week half price
- Senior citizens are given a £1 discount every day of the week

I am investigating the Rules module as the most feasible solution, but I am not sure it will deal with all the scenarios above.

I would appreciate any advice to help me reach a working solution.

Comment: Can we assume you have read http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/discounts-and-coupons ? Rules for discounts can access day of the week and user roles, as far as I see there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) for first requirement. You will need to add PRODUCT PRICING rule & check the day in condition. Just multiply the base price by .5 & you can apply what you wanted..
Anther things are user role based, so if a user has role of student in condition then do the same in another PRODUCT PRICING rule.

Add one more rule for senior citizen, check their user type & apply the new price.

These will work for sure..